# Exclude fields from beeing saved in node mongodb native

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm inserting documents using [node mongodb native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)  into a mongodb (sic!). My objects look like this:

```
var x = {
  field: 'value',
  _nonPersistentField: 'Do not save that'
};
```

What I want to achieve is, to prevent all fields prefixed with an underscore not to be saved. In the example above '_nonPersistentField' should not be saved.

Is there a way (except Object.defineProperty) to prevent these fields from being saved in node mongodb native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a pre-parser? Instead of using `save` from the mongo client, use:

```
function save( obj, callback ) {
    var tmp = {};
    Object.keys( obj ).forEach( function( key ) {
        if ( key.substr( 0, 1 ) !== '_' ) {
            tmp[ key ] = obj[ key ];
        }
    } );

    // Now that the object is filtered, use mongodb's client
    mongodb.save( tmp, callback );
}
```

Using this way, you're not even seeing the object creation and whatnot, instead of:

```
mongodb.save( obj, function( err, results ) {
} );
```

You're using:

```
save( obj, function( err, results ) {
} );
```

Comment: Though about that solution but I wanted to avoid creating new temporary object instances. But I think the performance impact for mapping can be neglected...

Comment: Performance on just creating an object is definitely not going to be a bottleneck. It's not that expensive :)

Comment: And using this function, you're not even "seeing" the object creation. You just code normally like `save( obj, function( err, results ) {} );`